# "initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite" error in flexsurvspline call

Tags: r, spline, survival-analysis

When I run flexsurvspline, from the flexsurv package, on the attached dataset , I get the following error for any k>1:

`flexsurvspline(Surv(time,dead)~1,data=input_df,k=2)`

```
Error in optim(method = "BFGS", par = c(gamma0 = 0, gamma1 = 0, gamma2 = 0, :
initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite
```

From reading other posts with similar issues, I gather this is likely an issue with the inits parameter, and that I might have to generate my own inits function for this particular dataset. But I haven't found any guidance on how to do this for spline fits or what goes into that parameter. Am I correct that this is what's causing the error, and if so how should an inits function be determined?

[input_df.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HwUsAiYTwU8uBMh3QGWf1zHt14BTBxFu/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the debugger you can see what's going on inside the function.  By specifying `debugonce(flexsurvspline)`, and then running the function, you can step through and see what's happening on each step.  (NB: capital `Q` gets you out of the debugging browser).  When I did that, I found that the because more than 30% of the data is in the first time (2), which is also the left boundary know, the function is setting the knots at:

```
Browse[2]> knots
          33.33333% 66.66667%           
0.6931472 0.6931472 1.0986123 2.5649494
```

Note that the first two knots are at the same value, which essentially breaks the function.  You can fix this by specifying the interior knot values directly on the log-time scale.

```
flexsurvspline(Surv(time,dead)~1,data=input_df, knots=c(1.8,2.3))
# Call:
# flexsurvspline(formula = Surv(time, dead) ~ 1, data = input_df, 
#                  knots = c(1.8, 2.3))
# 
# Estimates: 
#           est      L95%     U95%     se     
# gamma0   -3.475   -3.783   -3.167    0.157
# gamma1    3.021    2.785    3.257    0.120
# gamma2    4.294    3.341    5.248    0.487
# gamma3   -7.908  -10.305   -5.510    1.223
# 
# N = 428,  Events: 428,  Censored: 0
# Total time at risk: 1401
# Log-likelihood = -725.7712, df = 4
# AIC = 1459.542
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Adjusting the 33.3% knot to 0.693148 gives me lower AIC values than a 1-knot spline. Is there any disadvantage to specifying custom interior knot values?

Comment: Not really.  As you increase the flexibility of the model you have to be more careful about overfitting.